# Is unit norm gradient a necessary and sufficient condition for a signed distance function?

Tags: real-analysis, computer-science, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I've seen proof that a signed distance function $f$ satisfies the eikonal equation

$$\|\nabla_{\mathbf{x}} f(\mathbf{x})\| = 1, \mathbf{x} \in \Omega$$

where $\Omega$ is an open set with boundary $\partial \Omega$ such that $f|_{\partial\Omega} = 0$, and $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm.

However, the main [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eikonal_equation) for the eikonal equation makes a stronger claim than this: it states that the solution to this equation *is* the signed distance function.

I've seen similar claims in some papers; e.g., that the signed distance function is the viscosity solution to this eikonal equation. However, I haven't seen any lucid proofs of this fact.

So, is unit norm gradient equivalent to being a signed distance function?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You would need to study viscosity solutions to understand this. For example, chapter 4 in https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~jwcalder/viscosity_solutions.pdf